# To much wrapping in MVVM application with exposed API

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I have a desktop application developed using WPF and MVVM, that can be used as a library trough the exposed API.

My problem is that I find myself doing a lot of wrapping. For example I have a customer entity. This entity must be wrapped by the API in order to provide such functionality as Save(), Delete(), etc. In the same time the ViewModel used in the GUI needs to wrap the entity in order to provide the same functionality as the API and in order to add GUI specific properties like: IsSelected, IsExpanded, etc.

My solution to this problem was to wrap the exposed api in the ViewModel, and looks like this:

[image: Architecture of my application]

but I still have 3 classes for my customer:

1. an entity that maps the databases,
2. a model that is exposed trough the API and wraps the database entity,
3. and the view model that wraps the API model.

Adding a property requires me to do changes in 3 or 4 places, and a lot of my code is just boiler plate code, How can I design my application in order to do less wrapping?

Comment: It's unfortunate that your entity and model objects are different, but the existence of similar objects between your model and viewmodel is typical in my experience. When you're designing your VM, don't forget that VMs and Models live in fundamentally different solution spaces that happen to share similar models. Your VMs should be defined by the organization of your use cases. Your Models shouold be defined by the actual data being stored. I don't find it uncommon to have a single VM referencing multiple models, e.g., but exposing a subset of the properties from each.

Comment: @GregD: of course the case I was talking about does not happen every time since sometimes the GUI has simpler use cases that can use the API model directly, but since the project is big, the case of a ViewModel basically replicating my API model and just adding a few GUI properties is very frequent, and does bite my development time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a relatively simple design solution to this problem: the Extension Object Pattern.

The library provides the model and extension point:

```
public interface IExtension<T>
{
    void Initialize(T target);
}

// model class
public class Project
{
    ...

    public IExtension<Project> Gui
    {
        get { return serviceProvider.Get<Project>(this); } 
    }
}

// model class
public class Application
{
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<Projects> Projects { get { ... } }

    public IExtension<Application> Gui
    {
        get { return serviceProvider.Get<Application>(this); } 
    }
}
```

The desktop application instead of wrapping or inheriting my model uses the same api as the library, but implements the IExtension interface in order to  extend the model with methods, command and properties that are GUI specific.

The desktop application contains extensions like this:

```
class ProjectExt : IExtension<Project>
{
    Project project;

    public DelegateCommand OpenProjectCommand { get { ... } }
    public DelegateCommand SaveProjectCommand { get { ... } }
    public DelegateCommand CloseProjectCommand { get { ... } }

    public bool IsSelected { get { ... } set { ... } }

    ...
}
```

and injects the extensions by using a service provider. The Drawback is that the xaml is not as clean anymore because sometimes I have to reference properties and commands that are in the GUI extension and sometimes I reference the library api:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ProjectName}" /> <!--Library API-->
<Button Command="{Binding Gui.SaveProjectCommand}" /> <!--Gui extension-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend, rather than just wrap in a facade.

So using your implementation of MVVM, the model will extend (inherit from) the entity that maps to the database. Then any added properties get inserted at the right inheritance level.

It is quite normal to wrap a viewmodel around these models/entities prior to them being shown in the UI via binding, especially when a list is involved and you need to maintain per-item state or options. If your models/entities are starting to get quite large then you should consider using inheritance/extending here as well rather than wrapping. Repetitive wrapping of larger entities will lead very quickly to you violating the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) when you decide to start having overly deep binding paths because you no longer want to replicate each public property in each facade layer.

Once you start getting to this level of complexity I personally prefer changing the role of the model - instead of it being a representation of a data object it becomes the business layer responsible for the data repository actions. So it has a Save() and GetData() method, but it operates on the data entities and isn't a data entity itself. This cuts complexity - each model could potentially deal with several different data entities. It's a subtle change - the model becomes more akin to a client service or a controller, and you have models for *functional areas* rather than *data types*.

Comment: I did think about using inheritance instead of composition, the problem is that the solution falls short when using collections since the object in the collection will remain of base type instead of the ViewModel type. I didn't get in all the details but wrapping collections is probably the worst problem, since I have to keep them synchronized.